# jQuery Infinite Scroll with Masonry

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, infinity

I'm using Masonry and Infinite Scroll but the code below doesn't work !
Is that I forgot something in my HTML ?
All items are displayed at once !

```
<div id="containerPost">
<div id="post119" class="item rubColor1" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <p style="text-align:left;padding:5px 5px;font-weight:700">Test 1</p>
</div>
<div id="post118" class="item rubColor1" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <p style="text-align:left;padding:5px 5px;font-weight:700">Test 2</p>
</div>
<div id="post117" class="item rubColor1" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <p style="text-align:left;padding:5px 5px;font-weight:700">Test 3</p>
</div>
<div id="post116" class="item rubColor1" style="padding-bottom:10px">
    <p style="text-align:left;padding:5px 5px;font-weight:700">Test 4</p>
</div>
... and so on
```

```
    var $container = $('#containerPost');
$container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : '.pagination',    
        nextSelector : '.pagination a',
        itemSelector : '.item',
        loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
    },
    function( newElements ) {
        var newElems = $( newElements );
        newElems.css({ opacity: 0 });
        newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
        $container.masonry( 'appended', newElems); 
    }
);
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
})
```

Thanks for your help...

Chris

Comment: Can you post your whole html? Or put this in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I never used jsfiddle but I did this : http://jsfiddle.net/Sfmv9/ 
Hope that help ;))

Comment: You need to include the path to the masonry and infinite scroll libraries.

Comment: Thanks @msbodetti but it's include already !

Comment: No I mean into the fiddle..

Comment: I don't understand your answer ;((

Comment: And the script tags into the html section in your jsfiddle.net/Sfmv9 Upload it to a online server and link it in the src attribute for the script

Comment: @msbodetti : I already put all scripts in the "External Resources" of jsfiddle

Comment: Ok cool, see it now! See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The masonry is working now.

Instead of this:

```
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    })
```

Use this from the docs on http://masonry.desandro.com/:

```
$container.masonry({
       itemSelector: '.item'
    });
```

You probably should use another function to use the imagesloaded plugin.

[View updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sfmv9/3/)

Comment: Thanks @msbodetti but I cannot see the difference ! All items are displayed at once.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Masonry is working but I'm interested to work with Infinite Scroll too. This is what I'm looking for ;))

Comment: Infinite Scroll doesn't seem to have good documentation, how about using AnimOnScroll? The masonry plugin uses it as well, it works really well with it http://jsfiddle.net/Sfmv9/19/embedded/result/